# Set value of jQuery datepicker to value of another datepicker

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

I have 2 `datepicker`s on a page. Users are expected to enter 2 dates somewhat close to one another. However, if a user skips 6 months ahead, their intuition tells them that when they click the 2nd `datepicker`, it will *also* already be in that same month.

I need to set the defaultDate of the second `datepicker`, to the date selected in the first `datepicker`.

```js
$("#from").datepicker({
  defaultDate: new Date(),
  minDate: new Date(),
  onSelect: function(dateStr) 
  {         
      $("#to").val(dateStr);
      $("#to").datepicker("option",{ minDate: new Date(dateStr)})
  }
});

$('#to').datepicker({
  defaultDate: new Date(),
  onSelect: function(dateStr) {
    toDate = new Date(dateStr);
    fromDate = ConvertDateToShortDateString(fromDate);
    toDate = ConvertDateToShortDateString(toDate);
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input id="from">
<input id="to">
```

But it fails to run. In fact it fails to initialise the `datepicker`s at all.. And I'm not sure why. Just having them as normal `datepicker`s of course works fine.

Does anyone have any other methods of achieving my goal?

Comment: Also... ignore the snippet on here. It doesn't have jQuery 1.12 so cant really be used as a method to test.

Comment: Edit: I see you updated your answer. See this fiddle that includes jquery edge and jquery ui and this code works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/gLrumpo3/5/

Answer (score 0):

use the method "show" of jquery ui

```
    $('#to').datepicker({

        });

$("#from").datepicker({
            defaultDate: new Date(),
            minDate: new Date(),
            onSelect: function(dateStr) 
            {   
                    $("#from").datepicker( "hide" );
                $('#to').val(dateStr);
                $('#to').focus();
                $('#to').datepicker( "show" );
                $("#to").datepicker( "option", "minDate", endDate );
                        //$("#to").datepicker( "option", "maxDate", '+2y' );
            }
        });
```

the idea it's call to show for work it

i leave a jsfiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/roberburnday/btn7bp2v/](https://jsfiddle.net/btn7bp2v/)